# Auto assign child property to parent property EF Core

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have the following classes.

```cs
    public class Parent 
    {
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }

        public int BranchId { get; set; }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string GuidId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }

        // The PRIMARY KEY is ( CompanyId, BranchId, Id )
        // There is also a UNIQUE KEY ( GuidId )
        // Id column is SQL Server identity(1,1)
    }

    public class Child
    {
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }

        public int BranchId { get; set; }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string GuidId { get; set; }

        public int ParentId { get; set; }

        public string ParentGuidId { get; set; }

        public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }

        // The PRIMARY KEY is ( CompanyId, BranchId, ParentId, Id )
        // There is also a UNIQUE KEY ( GuidId )
        // Id column is SQL Server identity(1,1)
    }
```

I configure the relation between parent and child with the unique key as following

```cs
    // Parent
    builder.HasMany(p => p.Children)
        .WithOne(c => c.Parent)
        .HasPrincipalKey(p => p.GuidId)
        .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentGuidId);

    // Child
    builder.HasOne(c => c.Parent)
        .WithMany(p => p.Children)
        .HasPrincipalKey(a => a.GuidId)
        .HasForeignKey(a => a.ParentGuidId);
```

Because this relationship uses the `UNIQUE KEY` column (rather than the `PRIMARY KEY`), EF Core will only automatically populate the `ParentGuidId` property when loading related entities or when setting `virtual Parent Parent`, but I want EF Core to *also* populate the other properties.

For example:

```cs
Parent p = dbContext.Parents.Single( p => p.ParentGuidId == "(some GUID value)" );

Console.WriteLine( p.GuidId ); // "(some GUID value)" // OK!
Console.WriteLine( p.CompanyId ); // "123"
Console.WriteLine( p.Id ); // "456"

Child newChild = new Child()
{
    Parent = p
};

Console.WriteLine( newChild.ParentGuidId ); // "(some GUID value)" // OK!
Console.WriteLine( newChild.CompanyId ); // "123" // OK!.
Console.WriteLine( newChild.ParentId ); // "0" // This should be "456" instead.

dbContext.Childs.Add( newChild );
dbContext.SaveChanges(); // <-- Saved with `newChild.ParentId` = 0 and I want EF Core to map 'Parent.Id "456"' to 'newChild.ParentId'
```

The Child entity knows the CompanyId and BranchId because of I manually set every child entity to it's parent base data(CompanyId, BranchId, etc...)

Not the Child.Parentaid is missing because it filled by sql server identity.

I tried to `CREATE TRIGGER` on Child `INSERT` to edit the inserted data based on GuidId, but it fails because of transaction isolation level of ef core is ReadCommitted.

So trigger cannot read the `Parent.Id` while inserting Child because ef core transaction is not committed yet.

I hope anyone help me to find a solution to this problem, or advice to maybe change design of entities or relations?

Comment: Why are you using `String` instead of `System.Guid` for your "Guid" properties?

Comment: "I want to auto assign ParentId with the value of Parent.Id"  <-- Are you asking about your  _in-memory_ entity objects? Because if you also mean _inside the DB_ then what you really need is a `CASCADE` option on your FKs - and you do understand how EF handles loading, right? EF isn't magic - nor does EF update DB rows _live_ (i.e. setting a property does not cause an immediate `UPDATE` statement to be executed).

Comment: If you already have an existing database, please show us your `CREATE TABLE` statements for both `Parent` and `Child`, because it looks like you are not correctly configuring your entity classes. Also show us your **full** Model Configuration code.

Comment: Also, it's bad-practice to have columns named just "`Id`" because it introduces ambiguity when using multiple tables simulatenously (e.g. `Parent.Id` vs `Child.ParentId` vs. `Child.Id`). Foreign-keys' column names should also describe the nature of the relationship, not just match column names. Code should be self-documenting.

Answer (score 2):

A database should never store parent entity data in a child entity. One of the principal database design rules is never duplicating data. The related data can be read or updated by joining the parent and child tables. Duplicate data is an entirely unnecessary opportunity to have different values in the "duplicated" properties.

Comment: I think the OP is asking about auto-updating the _in-memory_ representation of loaded entities in their `DbContext` (as EF doesn't do that right now) rather than in the DB because otherwise that makes absolutely no sense, so I don't know why they mentioned using `TRIGGER` objects or mutating data at the DB-level at all, really)

Comment: @Dai Well, doesn't that indicate they want to store `ParentID` in the database as well? Which is indeed pointless. I would only use `ParentID` as a proper foreign key and, if really necessary, use `Parent.GuidId`.

Comment: @GertArnold I'm using the composite key (Company' Branch' etc...) as primary key to avoid data duplication. Since the data are collected from many applications into one database after sync and replication. And I'm using GuidId to make every row unique and simplify the relations between entities by GuidId